# Microsoft graph explorer daemon app create planner task

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

i'm trying to create an daemon app which should automatically get / create planner tasks.

I'm following this example of microsoft. See link: https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2

However i get unauthorized exception if i try to call "planner/tasks". I'm sure i gave the application the right access.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Planner APIs do not support application permissions. If you look at the API reference for those APIs, the permissions sections lists the supported permissions. From [List tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/planneruser-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions):

**Application**: Not supported.

Comment: Hi Jason, do you think there is a way to automate the process of login (select the user) in the beginning if the application doesn't do silent authentication because the application permission for planner api is not supported?

Comment: What you could do is have the user sign into your app once using one of the interactive flows to authorize and consent, being sure to request the `offline_access` scope. That gets you a refresh token along with the access token. You should be able to obtain fresh access tokens silently from there, but you'd need to be able to handle the case where the silent requests fail and somehow notify the user.